# Why doesn't my Object stop moving on transform.Translate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want an Object to make another Object move per transform.Translate but the Object doesnt stop moving when it reached its destination.

I've tried several things in my script but I had no specific idea what could be the problem. One thing is: I have several methods in my code which make several things move differently on different passages. So, I have written a small Method which executes the specific method on Input.GetKey() to see if it's the same when I execute no other method, additionally I've commented out everything called in Update to get sure. No other movement method should affect the object. Therefor I'll only post the affected Method which is called on GetKey in Update.

"transPointFirst" to "transPointFourth" are empty gameObjects passed in the Inspector. I've also checked if the transPoints are moving on runtime but nope, same position every frame.

```
private void ElevateCaptain()
{
    targetRigid.isKinematic = true;

    var transFirst = new Vector3(transPointFirst.localPosition.x, transPointFirst.localPosition.y, 0);
    var transSecond = new Vector3(transPointSecond.localPosition.x, transPointSecond.localPosition.y, 0);
    var transThird = new Vector3(transPointThird.localPosition.x, transPointThird.localPosition.y, 0);
    var transFourth = new Vector3(transPointFourth.localPosition.x, transPointFourth.localPosition.y, 0);

    target.transform.Translate(transFirst * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

    if (target.transform.position == transFirst)
        target.transform.Translate(transSecond * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

    else if (target.transform.position == transSecond)
        target.transform.Translate(transThird * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

    else if (target.transform.position == transThird)
        target.transform.Translate(transFourth * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

    else if (target.transform.position == transFourth)
    {
        targetRigid.isKinematic = false;
    }
}
```

So, I want my target to move to the first translation, if that is reached, move to the second translation and so on. Fact is: the target moves in the correct direction, but never stops. It doesn't matter if the code is executed like this, or if I leave out everything after the first transform.Translate call. The Object moves to that first point and further and further and further... Also the same when I choose another of these points as first Translation. I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: You have a transform.Translate that doesn't have an if check on it, so it will keep moving also, you are relying on == for 3 floats, would be better to use the vector3.distance and approximate function to check if they are the same positions.

Comment: @Eddge I've also tried to check the if condition with Vector3.Distance. But isn't transform.Translate supposed to move to that given point and no further?

Comment: No that would be move towards

Comment: @Eddge mentioned it in my answer but using `==` on two `Vector3`s already checks for approximate equality. Your first part is completely right.

Comment: @Ruzihm, I would rather be specific in my code as to what I am doing rather then leave it up to the api's specification that can change at any update.

Comment: @Eddge Unity very clearly distinguishes between `Equals` for exact equality and `==` and `!=` for approximate equality. Also, it would be better (faster) to use `(a-b).sqrMagnitude` than `Distance` to avoid the need for an expensive square root computation.

Comment: @Ruzihm Unity also very clearly distinguishes converting there objects to a bool statements for things like if(someObject).  They have also be discussing the removal of handling this for end users as they may want to use it for something else.  Like I stated previously I prefer to be specific in my code as to what I am doing, yes sqrMagnitude is more optimized but doing a square root isn't nearly as "expensive" as it used to be.  This isn't a question about optimizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going on here.

If your `transPointFirst`,`transPointSecond` etc have any parent gameobjects, comparing their `localPosition` to the `position` of `target` might have unexpected behaviors. It's probably best to compare their `position` fields directly. Also, if their Z components of their positions are already `0`, you don't need to create a duplicate `Vector3` of them.

`Translate` is expecting a direction vector multiplied by a distance but you are giving it what appears to be a position vector. You probably want to use [`Vector3.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) to calculate the position of `target` each frame. You'll need a variable to set the speed you'd want to move at, ideally it would be a public field so you can set it in the inspector.

Also, as Eddge said, you are doing that first `Translate` under every circumstance which goes against the logic you want.

However, in Unity, `Vector3`'s `==` and `!=` operators already check for approximate equality, so you are fine there.

You also need to consider what happens on frames when the object is between two positions. If you're calling `ElevateCaptain` on every frame while it is supposed to be moving, you can check if its current position lies between each sequential pair of points, or have some variables that keep track of what points it has "touched" so far.

An easier way for you to write what you want to do here could be to use [`Coroutine`s](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) then only call `ElevateCaptain` once, when you want it to start moving. Here's an example of what your code might look like with these changes and using coroutines:

```
public float elevateSpeed;
private bool captainElevating;

Start() 
{
    // ...
    captainElevating = false; 
    // ...
}

private void ElevateCaptain()
{
    if (!captainElevating) 
    {
        captainElevating = true;
        StartCoroutine("ElevateCaptainCoroutine");
    }
}

private IEnumerator ElevateCaptainCoroutine() 
{
    targetRigid.isKinematic = true

    while (target.transform.position != transPointFirst.position)
    {
        target.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
                target.transform.position,   
                transPointFirst.position,
                elevateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }

    while (target.transform.position != transPointSecond.position)
    {
        target.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
                target.transform.position,   
                transPointSecond.position,
                elevateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }

    while (target.transform.position != transPointThird.position)
    {
        target.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
                target.transform.position,   
                transPointThird.position,
                elevateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }

    while (target.transform.position != transPointFourth.position)
    {
        target.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
                target.transform.position,   
                transPointFourth.position,
                elevateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }

    targetRigid.isKinematic = false;
    captainElevating = false;
}
```

If you decide to go the `Coroutine` route, you should try to only call `ElevateCaptain` once when you want the target to **begin** moving, although the inclusion of the `captainElevating` variable should prevent it from being called while it's already happening.

Coroutine or otherwise, an improvement on this might be to use a `List` of `GameObject` and have the Coroutine loop over the list moving the `target` toward each one in turn. That way, in the inspector you can drag as many `transPoint` GameObjects as you'd like into the list and change it very easily. The repetitive structure of the coroutine approach lends itself very well to such a loop.

Comment: That totally works! Many thanks! I was actually trying to get this working with MoveTowards before but didn't think about using it again when I decided to set the Object to kinematic anyway, haha! I've also discussed about using a coroutine today but didn't get the point about it, until you came. But what I would have never thought of is using a while statement (maybe because it usually crashes my game). Thank you so much for your time and sharing your knowledge! Also the list is a nice idea I woudn't have thought of. Thank you!